# SendMessage WM_SETTEXT to TextBox doesn't trigger TextChanged Event

Tags: c#, winapi

I have code that gets the handle to a textbox control and uses the windows API to change the text.
The TextChanged event doesn't fire when the text is updated.

Is there a way to fire the TextBox.TextChanged event using the Windows API?

**[Update]**
I think the reason the event doesn't fire is because the textbox handle is sent though a DCOM interface. 
The program is a National Instruments TestStand shell written in c# and uses the NI TestStand COM object for the core functionality. In the TS sequence file (a sort of TS script language) I created an object reference for the textbox handle and set it using the TS api in the shell form's load event. After that I send the handle to my c# DLL. I use SendMessage to update the textbox and that works good. The problem is that the TextChanged event doesn't fire.

I tried using the TS interface to send the textbox and the TextChanged delegate and I couldn't get it to work. I think there is an AppDomain issue doing that through the TS COM object.

Answer (score 5):

As this program proves, the `TextChanged` event does fire when the control is sent a `WM_SETTEXT` message.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, 
            IntPtr wParam, string lParam);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero,
              textBox1.Text + ", " + textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that this original version of the answer was overly complex and used a `SendMessage` like this:

```
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, unit Msg, 
  IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

and consequently had to perform manual marshalling:

```
IntPtr text = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(textBox1.Text + ", "
  + textBox1.Text);
SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, text);
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(text);
```

Comments at this question ([Automatic casting for string DllImport arguments vs Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616445/automatic-casting-for-string-dllimport-arguments-vs-marshal-stringtocotaskmemuni/19616497?noredirect=1#comment29126007_19616497)) persuaded me to update.

Comment: i have a question, why not use `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` ?

Comment: @AppDeveloper You could use that also. Doesn't really matter either way. I tend to go for the COM heap with pinvoke since if ever the marshaller does deallocation then it uses the COM heap.

Comment: sorry , but just for curiosity, how does COM heap differ from a normal unmanaged memory pointer?

Comment: @AppDeveloper It's just a different heap. It also allocates an unmanaged pointer. Conceptually they are just the same. Any process can allocate from the COM heap and then any other code in that same process can deallocate that memory back to the common shared heap. And likewise for the HGlobal heap. It's probably got a real name! There are other heaps. You can p/invoke `HeapAlloc`. And there's also `VirtualAlloc`. Heaps aboud!

Comment: How would this example change if the target application (with textBox1) was another application?

Comment: @Amitabh You would need to adjust the code that discovers the target window handle. No other changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what text you're trying to change but I used a combination of PostMessages and keypresses (for numbers) into the textbox and it triggers the TextChangedEvent.

Look at method 2 of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19233518/2855937). It basically sets the mouse to click on the textbox and then send key presses of the text you want to the textbox (letter by letter).