# Automatic casting for string DllImport arguments vs Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni

Tags: c#, winapi, pointers, pinvoke

Consider the `WM_SETTEXT` message that you can use to set the text of another window via old school Win32 API. There are probably a multitude of ways of doing this in .NET, here's two that I know:

```
[DllImport("USER32", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);

SendMessage(handle, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "Magic String");
```

```
[DllImport("USER32", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

IntPtr textPointer = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni("Magic String");
SendMessage(handle, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, textPointer);
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(textPointer);
```

The first one uses a string in the declaration of the dll import and lets .NET handle it. This second uses an `IntPtr` and explicitly creates a pointer using `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni` and then freed using `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`. Both of these approaches work happily as far as I can tell.

Note I normally do the former (which in fact I used to do many years ago as a VB6 programmer), but I came across the latter on a comment on another StackOverflow post and was curious if the former was another bad habit that needed squashing.

I have also seen a variant of the first example using a `char[]` array in the declaration and passing in a `StringBuilder`

My question is simple - which (if any) is the correct way of doing it? For example, the `SendMessage` Win32 call only accepts pointers anyway, so "something" must be creating pointers behind the scenes for the first version, and if so does it do the cleaning up, or is it better to be verbose and use the explicit allocation and deallocation of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a parameter of `string`, the p/invoke marshaller will, behind the scenes, marshal that to a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters. The marshaller will handle all memory allocation and deallocation. You can do it yourself with an `IntPtr` parameter, but it comes to the same in the end.

Which you choose comes down to whether or not you plan to use the `SendMessage` declaration for any other messages that you send.

- If you only ever call `SendMessage` for `WM_SETTEXT`, then you declare it to receive a `string` parameter.
- If you also use `SendMessage` to send other messages, then you can declare the parameter to be `IntPtr` and perform the marshalling manually.
- And yet another option is to declare multiple overloaded variants so that you can make the code that calls `SendMessage` as convenient as possible for the programmer.

Now, let's pick up that last option. Suppose you needed to send `WM_GETTEXT` as well as `WM_SETTEXT`. For `WM_SETTEXT` you need to pass string data from managed to native, so you'd prefer `string`. For `WM_GETTEXT`, you need to supply a buffer so that the native code can fill out the window text. And that means you want to use `StringBuilder`. So, declare two overloads, one receiving `string` and one receiving `StringBuilder`. Use the former for `WM_SETTEXT` and the latter for `WM_GETTEXT`.

Comment: David - thanks for the helpful answer! As it turns out, it was actually a comment authored by yourself using `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni` that prompted this question in the first place :) I shall stick with the "let .NET sort it out" version I think. Thanks again!.

Comment: Out of interest, where is that comment?

Comment: Urg, I meant "answer" not "comment", sorry for the mixup. The answer was [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14634298/148962).

Comment: That was just how that example came out. I wasn't really thinking about large scale dev then, and that p/invoke probably came from somewhere else, perhaps pasted from pinvoke.net. Don't read too much into it.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, without hesitation!

Comment: Isn't updating the old answer a bad idea? Now none of the comments that follow it make any sense in the context of the new content. I guess it's sort of irrelevant either way due to the answer still being valid in accordance to the original question, but still...